# How to represent a book content in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a set of information which I want to represent in an array and then pull them out into a react native flat list but I don't know how to go about it.

Basically, there are different titles with subtitles and every subtitle has a content. I want to map through the list and display them.

[image]

Below is my code so far but it doesn't seem to work.

```js
const NigLawList= ({navigation}) => {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([
      {Law: "Evidence Act", id: "1",
      part:[ {name: "Title one", meaning: "Content is here"},
      {name: "Title 2", meaning: " Content is here"}
      
    ]

},
])
```

Comment: please provide more info on the code you are trying to execute and complete error

Comment: Actually, i dont have any code yet. I just want to know if i can display that kind of information in a react native flatlist

Comment: please check the image above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this way

```
const [data, setData] = useState([{"Law":"Evidence Act","id":"1","part":[{"name":"Title one","meaning":"Content is here"},{"name":"Title 2","meaning":"Content is here"}]}]);

renderSubtitleAndContent = (parts) => {
    return parts.map(part => {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>{part.name}</Text> <-- Subtitle here -->
          <Text>{part.meaning}</Text> <-- Content here -->
        </View>
      );
    });
 };

<FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Text>{item.Law}.</Text> <-- title here -->
          {this.renderSubtitleAndContent(item.parts)} <-- render Subtitle And Content -->
        )}
/>
```

Comment: This works fine but all the flatlist does not map through the names